# unable to use for loop output to set variable in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm using a for loop to acces a text file with a bunch of files + their directory formatted like this:

```
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie.mpg
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie2.mkv
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie3.mpg
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie4.mkv
```

I have to replace .mpg and .mkv with .xml, and then write that output away to another text file, which I'm trying to do like this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%~dp0temporary\movies.txt) do (
set string=%%A
set find=.mkv
set replace=.xml
set string=%%string:!find!=!replace!%%

set find=.mpg
set string=%%string:!find!=!replace!%%

echo %string%>>%~dp0temporary\xml.txt
)
```

The output I want is this:

```
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie.xml
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie2.xml
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie3.xml
//srv/something/somethingelse/movie4.xml
```

But what I get is this:

```
Echo is off.
Echo is off.
Echo is off.
Echo is off.
```

I have been searching on this for over an hour but I can't find anything that works

Comment: @Mofi I've done that; but I still get the same output. I've updated the question with the new code I use

Comment: You also need to change your variable-syntax. Take a look to the [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the rewritten batch code which produces the expected output from input file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "vidLoc=//srv"
set "resultLoc=c:"
del "%~dp0temporary\xml.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~dp0temporary\movies.txt") do (
    set "FileNameWithPath=%%A"
    set "FileNameWithPath=!FileNameWithPath:.mkv=.xml!"
    set "FileNameWithPath=!FileNameWithPath:.mpg=.xml!"
    set "FileNameWithPath=!FileNameWithPath:%vidLoc%=%resultLoc%!"
    echo !FileNameWithPath!>>"%~dp0temporary\xml.txt"
)
endlocal
```

All environment variable references enclosed in percent signs are expanded already on parsing entire **for** block. Just the environment variable references enclosed in exclamation marks are expanded delayed on executing the command. This can be seen on opening a command prompt window and running from there the batch file without `@echo off` at top or with this line being changed to `@echo on`.

Executing in a command prompt window `set /?` results in getting help of this command output on several window pages where usage of delayed expansion for **for** and **if** blocks is explained on a simple example.

And running in a command prompt window `for /?` prints help of command **for** into the output window.

For just replacing the file extension you could also use:

```
@echo off
del "%~dp0temporary\xml.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=*" %%A in ("%~dp0temporary\movies.txt") do (
    echo %%~dpnA.xml>>"%~dp0temporary\xml.txt"
)
```

But this faster code changes also all forward slashes `/` to backslashes `\` as the backslash character is the directory separator on Windows.

Comment: Another question, how can i use variables to find and replace something with your first code snippet? I need to find the content of the parameter %vidLoc% and replace it with the content of parameter %resultLoc% %vidLoc% will be on //srv and %resultLoc% will usually be on c:/, but sometimes on //srv also

Answer (score 0):

*Mofi* is right: move the line with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` out of any code block enclosed in `(`parentheses`)`.
However, try next approach using [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) modifier `~`:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions 
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%~dp0temporary\movies.txt) do (
    rem full_path=%%~dpnA
    rem extension=%%~xA
    echo %%~dpnA.xml 
)>%~dp0temporary\xml.txt
```